# put a string in condition (c++)

Tags: c++, string, conditional-statements

Why do i get an error for this line?

```
void Student::SetName(const string newName)
{
 if(newName!=NULL) //could not deduce template argument for 'const T1 *' from 'int'
{
     .....
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: p.s also tried if(newName) and got this error:

Comment: conditional expression of type 'const std::string' is illegal

Comment: If you're after an empty string, try `if (newName == "")`, or Bo's `if (!newName.empty())` There's no real verification comparison for string that I know of though.

Comment: A string cannot be NULL, but it can be `empty()`.

Comment: so if i want to put an empty string, i do newName=newName.empty(); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible solutions :

```
if(!newName.empty())

if(newName.size()) // If size = 0 so no caracters in string

if(newName == "") // Empty string
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't C#, a string in C++ is not a nullable type. Only pointers can actually be NULL, you can't define a variable without also assigning it some basic value in C++ except if you're using a pointer.

Your code should probably look like this:

```
if(!newName.empty())
    ....
```

Comment: so if i want to put an empty string, i do newName=newName.empty(); ?

Comment: @user1334761 `newName==""` or `newName.empty().

Comment: `.empty` is a boolean function. It does not return a string, it returns whether it is empty or not. Nor does it modify the contents of the string (@juanchopanza)

Comment: I know what `empty` is, but I am not sure what to "put an empty string" means. So I guessed (probably wrongly) that OP want to know how to check for string emptiness.

Comment: That makes sense. I was a little confused because I was sure you knew what it meant (by your karma).